# Allow users to customize layout using given variables

Tags: php

Let's say I have this array:

```
$meta = array(
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age' => 16,
    'e-mail' => 'john.doe@doedoe.com'
);
```

How Do I allow users to customize the layout using those variables? (And be able to catch errors). Here's my current idea:

```
extract($meta,EXTR_OVERWRITE);
$string = "Hi, I am $name. This is an $undefined_variable";
```

It isn't able to catch undefined variables though.

Comment: I don't understand what the downvote is for. I have shared what my concept is.

Comment: Use a template engine instead of this mess with global variables and variables-in-strings.

Comment: @ThiefMaster , PHP already is a templating language.

Comment: @tereško: It's still a mess when used like that.

Comment: well .. the problem is caused by global state, not by nature of PHP templates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
$string = "Hi, I am {{name}}. This is an {{undefined_variable}}";
foreach ($meta as $key => $value) {
    $string = str_replace('{{' . $key . '}}', $value, $string);
}
```

Or, if you could have `{{name}}`, etc, directly as keys in `$meta`, then:

```
$string = "Hi, I am {{name}}. This is an {{undefined_variable}}";
$string = str_replace(array_keys($meta), array_values($meta), $string);
```

Or, you could create and cache a `$meta` with `{{...}}` keys if you can't place them in the original one:

```
$metaTokens = array();
foreach ($meta as $key => $value) {
    $metaTokens['{{' . $key . '}}'] = $value;
}
```

Then, if you want to simply hide the undefined variables, by now you should have all the defined ones filled in, so anything else inside `{{..}}` should be an undefined variable:

```
$string = preg_replace('/{{.+?}}/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template class, based on [this article](http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html) (I try to avoid magic methods):

```
class Template 
{
    protected $parameters  = array();
    protected $filename = null;

    public function __construct( $filename )
    {
        $this->filename = $filename;
    }

    public function bind($name, $value) 
    {
        $this->parameters[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function render() 
    {
        extract( $this->parameters );
        error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        ob_start();
        include( $this->filename );
        error_reporting(~0); // -1 do not work on OSX
        return ob_get_clean();
    }

}
```

Basically ,you disable the warnings just before rendering the output, and then enable them again. This would let you render files, even if some variables have not been defined.